# Antd datepicker mask

Tags: javascript, datepicker, calendar, mask, antd

I am using [ANTD Datepicker](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#components-date-picker-demo-time) on my website and it works good. But I would like to add `mask` or similar feature so a user can easily enter date and time using a keyboard.

This is my current state: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QBXbxJ). For instance you can type, “hello, how are you” but I would like to accept only numbers in the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`. I think I need something similar to `Datepicker Mask`.

```
const { DatePicker } = antd;
const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York");

function onChange(value, dateString) {
  console.log('Selected Time: ', value);
  console.log('Formatted Selected Time: ', dateString);
}

function onOk(value) {
  console.log('onOk: ', value);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <DatePicker
      showTime
      format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
      placeholder="Select Time"
      onChange={onChange}
      onOk={onOk}
    />
  </div>
, mountNode);`
```

Comment: You don't need that because it's not useful for users

Comment: If you realy need to have this feature - use regex

Comment: Now I'm faced the same case. I'm trying to rewrite antpicker to make this happen (react mask input instead of usual input element)

Comment: Has anybody had any luck figuring this one out in a non-convoluted way? I'm facing the same challenge. Regex is not really an option since it's too expensive for what I'm building.